# BeautifulSoup and CSV: Delimiter after every Character

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape a wikipedia-page and write all h2-headlines without tags into a csv. Just a simple beginner task, I thought.

Now I have the problem, that a semicolon is set after every character in the csv.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84gypten"
r = requests.get(url).content


soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    # Output is okay
    print(h2.get_text())

    with open('Daten/Test.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
        write_h2 = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        write_h2.writerow(h2)
```

The output in the csv looks like follows:

```
I;n;h;a;l;t;s;v;e;r;z;e;i;c;h;n;i;s

ܻb;e;r;b;l;i;c;k

L;a;n;d;e;s;n;a;m;e

G;e;o;g;r;a;p;h;i;e

B;e;v;��k;e;r;u;n;g

G;e;s;c;h;i;c;h;t;e

P;o;l;i;t;i;k

M;i;l;i;t;伲

V;e;r;w;a;l;t;u;n;g;s;g;l;i;e;d;e;r;u;n;g

S;o;z;i;a;l;e; ;L;a;g;e

W;i;r;t;s;c;h;a;f;t

T;o;u;r;i;s;m;u;s; ;u;n;d; ;V;e;r;k;e;h;r

K;u;l;t;u;r

L;i;t;e;r;a;t;u;r

W;e;b;l;i;n;k;s

E;i;n;z;e;l;n;a;c;h;w;e;i;s;e

N;a;v;i;g;a;t;i;o;n;s;m;e;n;�
```

I am very new to programming, so I would be thankfull, if your answer is easy to understand for a newbie.

The output to the console works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writerow take list as input so you have to pass the list of strings, if you pass string it will consider it as list of characters.

See below example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84gypten"
r = requests.get(url).content


soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    # Output is okay
    h2_text = h2.get_text()

    with open('Daten/Test.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
        write_h2 = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        write_h2.writerow([h2_text])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the string `h2.get_text()` as a list

So you have to replace the final line:

```
with open('Daten/Test.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
    write_h2 = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    write_h2.writerow([h2.get_text()])
```